# Create multiple tables of the same type in a database (MySQL/MariaDB)

Tags: mysql, database-design, mariadb

I am trying to find a quick way of creating multiple tables in a database.  This is what I tried.

```
USE FILESERVER;
CREATE TABLE FILESERVER.FS01 ,FILESERVER.FS02, FILESERVER.FS03 ,FILESERVER.FS04, FILESERVER.FS05 ,FILESERVER.FS06
(
    'FOLDER' VARCHAR
    ,'NUMBER OF FRAGMENTS' INT
);
```

Obviously this is the incorrect syntax.  Any ideas?

Comment: usually not best practice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

build one you like - keep it empty...

then:

```
create table new_table as select * from existing_table;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can start from mysql manual create syntax
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-table.html

It is possible to create only one table

```
CREATE TABLE `fs01` (
  `folder` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `number of fragments` int(11) DEFAULT NULL
)
```

others can be created as copy of structure of fs01

```
CREATE TABLE fs02 LIKE fs01;
CREATE TABLE fs03 LIKE fs01;
CREATE TABLE fs04 LIKE fs01;
```

Hope it helps